# Achieve true determinism in CPLEX

Tags: python, cplex

I'm unable to achieve true determinism in CPLEX (I'm using the DOCplex python API).
Even if the best integer optimal solution is found without going to timeout (so it is expected to be unique), two identical separate runs leads to different results.

I'm setting the model parameters in this way:

```
cplex_model.parameters.randomseed = 42
cplex_model.parameters.threads = 1
```

Also I'm fixing every random seed that could be involved:

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run on different machines then you have no MIP determinism

Let me quote documentation

> By default, CPLEX employs parallel algorithms only as long as the
> optimization remains deterministic. In this context, deterministic
> means that repeated solving of the same model with the same parameter
> settings, including limits, on the **same computing platform** will follow
> exactly the same solution path, yielding the same level of performance
> and the same values in the solution.

Comment: I get different results on the same machine. I think that the system load could be involved so I disabled the concurrency but still non deterministic.

Comment: Then this looks like a bug and you should open a support request